# How do you get high resolution plots in applications using the Mathematica MathService?

Tags: export, mathlink-or-wstp, mac-os-x

This is for Mac users only using [MathService](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5180/) (MathService it seems, given that it was created back in 2004, is a power pc code and requires [Rosetta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_%28software%29) to run on Intel).

If I type a plot command in another application (in this case TextEdit):

[image]

...and then use Mathematica to evaluate that code within that application using MathService:

[image]

...all works fine.

[image]

But the problem then arises when you want to print the document because the graphic is at screen resolution. Does anyone know how to use MathService to generate print quality plots within other applications?

Also in MS Word it seem that only the "Evaluate to Text" service is available which (obviously) returns `FullForm` of the plot rather than the graphic. Why isn't "Evaluate to Graphic" available?

Incidentally using Mathematica this way seems to allow multiple undos of kernel evaluations.

Comment: Can increasing `ImageSize->...` option to 'Plot` help ?

Comment: No. it has no effect. But it is nice to be able to continually undo these evaluations. Wish you could do that natively in Mma.

Comment: Any idea what format the graphic is in?  (The service isn't working on my computer for some reason.)

Comment: @Brett. no. Any idea how I would identify the format once it has been inserted into the document? I am using 32 bit 10.6.8 but I have used MathService on and off for several years with 10.4 and 10.5. Are you using Lion? (I have never tried MathService on my 64 bit laptop)

Comment: @Brett. Just tried running MathService on my 64 bit laptop and it says Rosetta is required. That is the thing that runs pre-intel code right? i.e. allows non intel stuff to be emulated?

Comment: Have you tried the option `ImageResolution`?

Comment: `ImageResolution` is not an option for `Graphics`. If you wrap `Show` around it and use `ImageResolution` you get a pink box. In principle this could be very useful -- for Mac users anyway. You often read about people want seamless import of Mma stuff into Word etc. If MathService was updated and vector graphics were used instead of bitmap is makes it a very useful feature. And as above you can do multiple undos this way.

Comment: How about `Rasterize[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}], ImageResolution -> 300]` ?

Comment: @Spartacus good suggestion but unfortunately that has no effect. Still renders at screen resolution. I think we probably need to see the internal code/workings of MathService to figure this out.

Comment: If none of the options have effect, I suppose that the MathService is specifically designed to prevent their use, presumably to save bandwidth and/or CPU time.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I can't run MathService on Lion, but since Mathematica is scriptable it shouldn't be too hard to write an Automator workflow that does something similar (provided the text editor you're using is scriptable too).

Comment: @Heike Apple dropped Rosetta from Lion which is why MathService won't run. I've asked Wolfram if they plan to make an Intel version of this. I've used Automator for a few things from time to time but it seems like MathService is something that Wolfram should update to Intel because Apple made the switch, what 5 years ago??

Comment: The short answer is no, there is no way to generate a graphic in a format other than TIFF.  When I get a chance I'll update it to allow PDF (vector) graphics and compile it for Intel.

Comment: @ragfield would you make the code available to users to inspect and modify/compile themselves?

Comment: @ragfield Could you make your comment above an answer?

Comment: @ragfield have you been able to update this code yet?

Comment: @ragfield have you had a chance to update the code yet?

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

1) Open Automator and create a new Service.

2) In the search box, type "Run Apple Script" and drag the action into the workflow space on the right.

3) Replace the sample script (changing MyName appropriately) with:

```
on run {input, parameters}
set inputResult to (input as string)
set cmd to " -run 'Export[\"~/Desktop/test.pdf\"," & input & "];Exit[]'"
set mathPath to POSIX path of file ((path to application "Mathematica" as text) & "Contents:MacOS:MathKernel")


do shell script mathPath & cmd
set the clipboard to (alias "Users:MyName:Desktop:test.pdf") as «class furl»

tell application "System Events"
keystroke "v" using {command down}
end tell

end run
```

4) Hit the hammer icon to verify the code, then save the file to give the service a name.

5) In TextEdit try something like

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,Pi},PlotStyle->{Dashed,Red},ImageSize->500]
```

or

```
Style[TraditionalForm[Integrate[Gamma[Pi x]y[x],{x,0,2}]],FontSize->48]
```

It will embed a high quality PDF, saving the temp file to the desktop.

Comment: (+1) I like the keystroke trick to do the pasting! Pasting from clipboard is something Automator doesn't have out of the box. I recall using keystrokes like that when controlling an old non-scriptable application (Rita), and it comes in handy here. My main general concern is that for bad input, Mathematica scripts could run really long or lead to zombie processes if they fail. If that happens enough times you suddenly won't be able to start a new MMA process. So I would wrap the MMA input in `TimeConstrained`.

Comment: Good idea, Jens. This was admittedly a bit of a hack which is why I just saved the file to the desktop. Since I use LaTeX for just about everything I don't have much need of this service. But I got curious about services and wanted to see if I could create one to do what the OP was asking in a transparent way.

Comment: I can't get this to work -- an applescript error is returned. The temp PDF is saved to the desktop but when i look at the clipboard it is empty but nothing has been pasted in the TextEdit document.

Comment: I assume the PDF file has the proper plot which means the first half is working. Did you change the "MyName" in the code to the proper path? I think Applescript has built in alias paths for the desktop, but I just hardcoded it here.